how to attach file into pdf using console commands (shell)
I currently have a project in which I need to automate file attachment to a .pdf file using Excel VBA.
Is it possible to attach a file (.xml) to a .pdf file using only console commands or Windows Powershell? I am using Windows 11 and have read this manual about the possibilities of using pdf24 functions with console commands only, but can't find anything about file attachments.
https://creator.pdf24.org/manual
I've successfully attach some files into the pdf using the Sendkeys commands in VBA on an opened window of pdf24, but it is not reliable since I emulate some mouseclicks on a certain location of the monitor. Which made the positioning dependent on the monitor's resolution.
Thanks in advance

Well, the user has already got used to it and wants to continue creating his "receipt".pdf with Excel. but for about a year now it has been mandatory to embed the .xml e-receipt in this PDF.
